# After pressing home button and go back to game there apears a black screen for a while

Tags: android, andengine, delay

I'm using `Andengine` to develop my game.

I have a little problem when I'm pressing Home (or lock screen) and resume the game. There is a relative big delay (about 5-7 seconds) while the game reloading, and in this time, there appears a black screen. I'm afraid that users can consider that there is a problem with the game.

I think to reload a splash screen (or smth) but unfortunately I do not know how to do it. I tried put it into `onPause`/`onResume` methods, but with no effect.

My `MainActivity extends LayoutGameActivity class`, if it does matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can add a simple splash screen by following this tutorial: [Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)

You can also look into adding a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html), which is a visual indicator of progress in some operation. Displays a bar to the user representing how far the operation has progressed; the application can change the amount of progress (modifying the length of the bar) as it moves forward.

*A progress bar can also be made indeterminate. In indeterminate mode, the progress bar shows a cyclic animation without an indication of progress. This mode is used by applications when the length of the task is unknown. The indeterminate progress bar can be either a spinning wheel or a horizontal bar.*

Comment: the game was loaded, the problem appears when I paused the game, and then resume it. At first load, appears a slash scene with progress bar.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question properly.Well i don't think i can help much here. Hmm, have you tried this link: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/34674 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307126/black-screen-before-splash-screen-apper-in-android

Comment: Thanks. You give me an idea that could work. I would try to make a simple android dialog that will start on onResume.