# How to make a starting view/activity like youtube, reddit and twitter and so on?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In android when you start YouTube you get a view for couple of seconds then start what is after that, like this image attached

[Example of Youtube app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYxY6.png)

[another example of reddit app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um0dY.png)

my approach is create an activity and in onCreate i declare an countdowntimer for seconds just like this code:

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            startActivity(new Intent(WelcomingActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
```

is this a good way to do it ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Check this https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/ You wont need to setup a timer

Comment: It is called a splashscreen

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a very lightweight activity to show as a curtain while the rest of the application is starting. Thus, rather than having a countDown, you should listen an event signaling the application is ready.

Comment: Its a duplicate question please check questions before posting For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31251185/3272539

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Prevent white screen at startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437037/android-prevent-white-screen-at-startup)

Comment: It's hard to search for something you don't know what the term is

Answer (score -1):

1. **Create SplashScreenActivity.java**:

   ```
   public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                   finish();
               }
           }, 2000); // your screen will disappear after 2 seconds
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Register activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`**:

   ```
   <activity android:name="SplashScreenActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
3. **And create a layout for your splash screen**: activity_splash_screen.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/gradient_background" >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:src="your_image" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way to it is

make an activity called splash
then inside the xml for the activity place your logo you want to use in either an ImageView or as a

```
android:background  //in your </LinearLayout>
```

then in the java class of the activities onCreate simply write

```
 int secondsDelayed = 2;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Login.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
}
```

Comment: I would inmediately uninstall an app which wastes my time doing nothing... Don't do that please!