# Black screen appears before splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

when I launch my application, there is a black screen that appears for few moments and then only splash screen appears.I followed some of the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307126/black-screen-before-splash-screen-appear-in-android) thread but none worked.What might be the actual cause of it? can anyone help? I have pasted the code below.

`SplashScreenActivity.java`

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3 * 1000;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Util.doGuestLoginAndCheckForExpireDate();

        UserDetail.deleteUserDetailJson();
        Util.setProfileFetchStatus(false);
        // Start animating the image
        final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoImageViw);

       final  TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 1200f, 0f);
        anim.setDuration(1200);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);

        splash.startAnimation(anim);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                splash.setAnimation(anim);

                if (Util.getLoginStatus()) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, RestActivity.class));
                } else
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, AppIntroduction.class));

                finish();

            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }
}
```

This is the`theme` I've included in `Application tag` inside `Android manifest.xml` file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Anything Am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Comment the animation section & check

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade did that but still the same problem.

Comment: Check the methods that are called before ImageView Intialization may be they are taking long time to complete their respective task

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya I tried running an app by commenting all the lines above  initialization of image view part , but the problem  still persists

Comment: code inside Runnable's run method put ui update code in runOnUIThread method then check.

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya  inside the run method of handler, I defined  runOnUiThread( new Runnable) and placed all code inside its run method, but the problem still exists.May be there is something wrong with the theme I am using??

Answer (score 1):

You´ll see black or white depending on chosen theme till the main activity is created, to reduce the time don´t do anything intense in onCreate just set the layout you can move your code to onStart() or onResume() in the linked thread you also see that he set´s android:windowBackground to set the initial background of the activity while loading, can be static image or color

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I updated gradle, I changed it back to prebeta release to fix it.
From:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
}
```

To:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```