# Why FirebaseApp initialization is very slow,How to reduce app start time

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making one android app,earlier i have used gcm for push notification,right now I am trying  firebase cloud messaging  for sending push notifications.I have implemented firebase cloud messaging functionality in my app it is working fine but problem is it is taking too much time when app launches first time,please help me

```
build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.next.fcm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do not compile whole fcm lib just compile below line.

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"
```

Comment: i didn't get,should i add offline support to studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496625/my-application-taking-so-much-time-to-launching-first-activity-screen