# How To fix instant app Start up?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-theme

I have a set my Application Theme in

```
android:windowDisablePreview= true
```

then my application icon to click Not open App instant App Open after 1-2 seconds after,

So, How I can resolve this issue.

Thank in Advance...

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496625/my-application-taking-so-much-time-to-launching-first-activity-screen/37498162#37498162

Comment: disable your instant run in android studio.

Comment: Please clarify your query.What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I disable my instant run then Not working...

Comment: My Application Theme in set 
android:windowDisablePreview= true,                                                              then Device in Click to App, But App is not Lunch instant..                                Step 1 : Click to App                                                                                          Step 2 : App Not Launch instant (Launch After 2-3 Seconds Take)