# Make starting up an Activity in a different process faster

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, process

From my own app I'm starting an Activity that needs to be in another process, declaring it in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="ActivityName"
        android:process=":DifferentProcess"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

And starting it with an Intent as usual.

This new Activity creation always shows a white screen between activities; it's OK on a device like Nexus 5X, but on low-end devices the white screen appears for 1-3 seconds.

Is there anything I can do about it? Either make it faster or show a "Loading..." view while the process starts up?

Comment: BTW, if someone's wondering why I have it in a different process, it's because I needed it to have control over the back pressed of a UnityPlayer I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

In your theme add this tag

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

this will disable the white screen between activities.

On startup You can use a splash screen to hide the blank screen. Now an activity level splash screen. But splash screen as a background.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307263/4804264