# Xamarin Android and the splash screen

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Developing a cross-platform application with PCL I noted that the Android app starts with a blank screen with the title of the app. After a while my First ContentPage is showed. Can I remove the First blank screen? If not, Can be customized? Where is declared/defined? 
Thank you

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/

Comment: Ok... But this doesn't answer. I seen this giude. In my app created from the standard vs 2015 the splash theme is not defined. In my project I have nothing of what described in the guide.

Comment: Please use the search function of SO.. with that you can find tons of questions/answers depending on this topic. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19826738/2653134 (after 10 seconds of search)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black screen before Splash screen appear in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307126/black-screen-before-splash-screen-appear-in-android)